# moto g5 plus - male to female usb cable

Tags: usb

I am in the process of planning out the 3d print of a custom phone stand for my MG5+.  I am planning that the phone, in its protective case, will slide down onto the stand and plug into the usb port, to charge and access my wifi.

Examination of the phone vs what is on the Internet suggests that the usb port is a micro standard type B.

Ideally the phone will slide onto the male plug.  That is corrected out the back of the phone stand to a female plug.   My normal MG5% charger will plug into that.

So far Google-fu hasn't turned up any cables like this.  I see lots with the correct gender that carry power, but no data.  There are lots of OTG type cables that are power only.

So apparently no one sells a micro usb type b male to micro usb type b female cable that carries power and data.  I am not keen on making one.  The last time, I soldered two fingers together :(

**What other options are available?**

Comment: Ideally such docks are supposed to contain a small piece of circuit board inside where the power/data lines are wired on, plus some minor protection circuits.

Comment: Also, on our local site Taobao, lots of such cables are available, and many claim to do data too (e.g. [this one](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=531733484392) - Chinese page). Too bad it's near impossible for people outside of China to take the benefit of Taobao, though.

Comment: Most Moto devices come with a separate charger base and cable... Why wouldn't you just use a normal microUSB to USB cable and connected it to the Moto charger, or just get a QC charger online and carry your stock charger for travel/work?

Answer (score 1):

My google fu improved today.

**micro usb standard type b data cable extender**  yields multiple options.

Comment: Hehe, if there's something reasonable you want, Chinese would make it and Google will find it for ya :)